# Which would be best for a scalable environment?

Tags: performance, relational-theory

Which is more advantageous,  speaking of performance, and best practices?

A table of customers and a table of suppliers and a table of seller

Or

A table that covers the three entities having a field that defines whether the record is a customer, supplier and seller.

Remembering that the same person can be both a customer, a supplier or a seller and all has complete registration with data common people

Answer (score 0):

> Which would be best for a scalable environment?

No difference with the information provided. It would specifically depend on the amount of data for each type, and the use cases / queries you'd be running.

From a management and relational integrity perspective, keeping them as separate entities and tables would probably make more sense though. This is the typical approach ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) systems use too.

Answer (score 0):

> speaking of performance

Shows you're already suffering premature optimisation. Let's first get clear what are the logical requirements.

I think the answer is in your question. Also from @J.D.'s answer:

> This is the typical approach ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) ...

Yes, ERP's are the gold standard for best practice design. A "field that defines whether ..." is usually a symptom of a `person` table that's been stretched beyond its original design.

> Remembering that the same person can be both a customer, a supplier or a seller and all has complete registration with data common people

So there's some attributes common across all `person`s, irrespective of their particular role(s). And some specific to a role. 'Making space' for all possible roles (presumably by nullable attributes for those inapplicable) will be wasteful.

> can be both a customer, a supplier or a seller

Unclear: Does that mean customer and/or supplier and/or seller? That is up to 7 possible values for some status/indicator attribute, with 7-value logic to examine it depending what the query wants?

How about a `person` who has "complete registration with data common people" but hasn't yet been allocated any particular role? Typical business procedures are to register the `person` first, then check their credit score etc before starting any transactions. So possibly a 8th value for that pending status.

So:

- Put the person-in-general attributes in a `person` table.
- Put the additional customer-specific attributes in a `customer` table.
- Put the additional supplier-specific attributes in a `supplier` table.
- Put the additional seller-specific attributes in a `seller` table.

Now you've no need to maintain/examine some status flag:

- If your query wants persons-in-general query the `person` table.
- If your query wants customers query the `person` join `customer` tables.
- If your query wants suppliers query the `person` join `supplier` tables.
- If your query wants sellers query the `person` join `seller` tables.

Answer (score -1):

I have always had them in the same table in my applications for decades.  The reason being that my business logic is in triggers and stored procedures.

In the application itself,  I  have modules such as address, personal information, and accounts. These get pasted on the client, employee, seller and supplier forms.

Taking address module as an example, all the datatbase, code, validation, linking to Google maps etc is one place.

There is no effect on access speed if correct indexing is in place.

Comment: Business logic in triggers/SPs is terrible design. (Yes sometimes you're forced to do that because a DBMS doesn't support you expressing the business logic/validation explicitly; but this example doesn't stretch such limitations.)